# Check that login is successful into a website using java

Tags: java, authentication

I am using a code to login to a website. I am making a Get call first, to get the form parameters.
Then i am sending my login credentials, in the form, by a post call to the website.
I am getting a result like this:

Sending 'POST' request to URL : https://abc.ef.edu/login.asp

Post parameters : userName=xyz&password=xyz&Login=Sign+In

Response Code : 200

Does this result mean that i have logged into the website?
if yes, how can i check?
if no, then how can i login?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't mean you've logged in, it just means you pulled back a page over the web.

To test for login, you would need to "decorate" the page with some token of data (on successful login), then parse the response and look for it.

For example  < !-- YOU_LOGGED_IN -->

Then search for that string.

That or create a trimmed down test version of the page that just returns the token.

Answer (score 0):

That code is an HTTP response code which means that your login page was found (agais a 404 that you get when a page is not found). It has no bearing on the status of authentication. Even if the login fails, you'll still receive the HTTP code 200 only.

Comment: so does that mean that i have atleast placed my username and password successfully in the login page? 
if yes, then how to write the code to activate the login button?

Comment: That depends on how login.asp has been written.

Comment: i have checked the login.asp and have place the credentials according to the field names on the form.

Comment: Your login.asp should print out a message on the web page. Both if the login succeeds or if not. If you post the code here perhaps someone can tell if there's a problem there.